# how to save Sparql endpoints in RDF format by Apache Jena?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, endpoint

I'm wondering how to save Sparql endpoints in RDF format by Apache Jena (or other tool) ?
I have used

```
CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o }
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
LIMIT 10
```

and got the data but I need to save them local in my laptop!

P.S. (I have to handle the DBpedia sparql endpoints)

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this, this is an extremely inefficient way to take a copy of a public endpoint and is often frowned upon in the same way that bulk web crawling is.

Many public endpoints like DBPedia actually publish data dumps which you can download and work with locally, in the case of DBPedia see http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39 for the current downloads